# How to get Y position of a <View> element by reference?

Tags: android, react-native, view, measure

I have a `<View>` element. Now I would like to make a reference to the View and get the Y position in a different place, instead of using the `onLayout` attribute. Would this be possible?

Here is what I've tried:

```
let viewRef = useRef(null);

function myEvent() {
    if( viewRef ) {
        viewRef.measure((x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY) => {
            console.log(x, y, width, height, pageX, pageY);
        });
    }
}

<View ref={viewRef}></View>
```

However, viewRef remains `null`. An ideas?

Comment: Just to be sure, the <View> at the end with ref, is that all you return in the component?
Also note, usually youll have to get the data of the reference with "viewRef.current" and not directly from viewRef

Comment: @Shai, there's a lot of data returned, but I didn't want to flood the question with my entire file. Would that change anything? I only want to make a reference to a `<View>` and didn't succeed in the first step.

Comment: Im asking because on paper the ref you showed should work, but if in the view, the ref is inside another component for example, youll need a forward ref for it to work, also notice the reference isnt created with the component, so on the first render it would always be null, do know if that matters for your issue

Comment: Ah, I see, it does matter! Thank you. I need the reference immediately, otherwise it wouldn't matter. Thank you

Comment: You can do it with useEffect and in its dependecies to follow the ref and check if it exists, but first render will be null